# datetime2 doesn't expand months in \DTMDisplaydate

Tags: datetime2

I want to use strings for dates in my document that can be formatted either as ISO or German later on.

I looked at `isodate` `datetime` and `datetime2` most promising seemed to be the latest, but the months don't show up in German.

However in a document

```
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetstyle{german}
\today
\DTMDisplaydate{2017}{3}{8}{-1}
```

`\today` is expanded correctly as 8. März 2017, but `\DTMDisplaydate{2017}{3}{8}{-1}` results in 8. 3 2017 which is not correct, it should either be heute 8. 3. 2017 or 8. März 2017

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner might know the answer

Comment: There is no style `german`. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: There's a bug in the first letter upper case style. I'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the expected output, just use `\DTMdisplaydate` rather than `\DTMDisplaydate`:

> 9. März 2017
>   8. März 2017

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% ...or load \usepackage[ngerman]{datetime2} below

\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetstyle{german}

\begin{document}

\today

\DTMdisplaydate{2017}{3}{8}{-1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For [`datetime2-german`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-german), `\DTMDisplaydate` should be the same as `\DTMdisplaydate`, but I made an error (mostly probably from copy and pasting from another language file that has lower case months). The simplest method is to use Werner's solution (just use `\DTMdisplaydate`). If you need `\DTMDisplaydate` (for example, you may be switching languages), then either wait for version 1.1 2017-03-09 (which I've just uploaded) or redefine the style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\DTMrenewdatestyle
{german}%
{% 
  \renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{%
    \DTMifbool{german}{showdayofmonth}%
    {\DTMgermanordinal{##3}\DTMgermandaymonthsep}%
    {}%
    \DTMgermanmonthname{##2}%
    \DTMifbool{german}{showyear}%
    {%
      \DTMgermanmonthyearsep
      \number##1 % space intended
    }%
    {}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\begin{document}

\today.
\DTMDisplaydate{2017}{3}{8}{-1} 

\end{document}
```